# MagicMouse and Trackpad Orbiting/Zoom

Tags: interface, customization, osx

Here is my set up: I'm running Blender 2.76 on a Macbook with an Magicmouse attached. I'm quite happy that in this version as opposed to older versions (this changed around 2.6ish) the two finger dragging on the trackpad acts more naturally (rotating instead of zooming) but unfortunately this messes up the magic mouse as well (scrolling is changed to rotating as opposed to zooming). [This video](https://youtu.be/T-JHogscHJ8?t=48s) illustrates a method to return this to the old way, but this removes the new trackpad behaviour.

Is there a way to have the trackpad behave the new way while having the magic mouse behave the old way at the same time?

Comment: I don't think Blender can distinguish between the two devices. I think OS X sends Blender cursor and scroll data and Blender handles it according to Blender's Prefs. If I were you I'd either get a 3-btn Logitech (or equivalent) mouse, or learn to use Blender with the Emulate 3-btn Mouse setting enabled using only the Magic Trackpad.

Comment: What I've been currently doing is using my mouse to rotate and pinching to zoom on my trackpad with my other hand. There might be a way to combine this with and extra utility such as bettertouchtool to distinguish between the two?

Comment: Honestly, when you alternate between two input devices like that you lose valuable time as your hand changes position. It's more effective to have one hand reserved for keyboard shortcuts and the other for your mouse or trackpad. A 3-button mouse is the most natural solution, but a trackpad is also totally workable with "Emulate 3-button Mouse" enabled - just takes some getting used to. Even with BetterTouchTool or MagicPrefs you can't physically feel where the buttons are on a Magic Mouse.

Answer (score 3):

This answer might be a bit late for you but may help other users.
I have found that ctrl + trackpad-scrolling or ctrl + magic-mouse-scrolling zooms.